# Get folders that contain a certain number of directories

Tags: c#, getdirectories

So right now I have a list of directories that I wanted through a regex pattern and a linq filtering. What I need a way to get folders that contain a certain number of directories and skip the ones without 1 and how to check if my directory info is empty or not . Any suggestions ?  so this is what i have so far

DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\jphillips\Desktop\test");
      var dirs = new List();
      dirs = root.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => reg.IsMatch(d.Name)).Where((d => !d.FullName.EndsWith("TESTS"))).Where(d => d.GetFiles().Length > 3).ToList();

```
  foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(dir.FullName);
  }
```

can someone tell me how to filter it from here, and also what does * mean in get directories function

Comment: Can you post the code you've got so far?

Comment: I suggest you have a go yourself and post your code when you get stuck. That will make your question 100% better. We help best when you ask a good quality question.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a starting point i suppose:

```
var diProjects = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Projects");
var subFolders = diProjects.GetDirectories();
for (var i = 0; i < subFolders.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] {1}, directories = {2}, files = {3}"
        , i
        , subFolders[i].FullName
        , subFolders[i].GetDirectories().Length
        , subFolders[i].GetFiles().Length));
}
```

The following line gets the number of directories within the specified folder, you can check to see if its equal to 0 or what ever value you need to check against

```
subFolders[i].GetDirectories().Length
```

Also you can use the following to get the number files in a subdirectory

```
subFolders[i].GetFiles().Length
```

If both `subFolders[i].GetDirectories().Length` and `subFolders[i].GetFiles().Length` are 0 then you can assume the subdirectory is empty. You should be able to use this code as a template to do what you want.

Comment: this is what I got so far: DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\visrep01\REPORTS");
      var dirs = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
      dirs = root.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => reg.IsMatch(d.Name)).Where((d => !d.FullName.EndsWith("TESTS"))).Where(d => d.GetDirectories().Length >= 0).Where(d => d.GetFiles().Length > 3).ToList(); can someone tell me from here where i can go

Comment: my new problem is i have obtained all the directories and subdirectories in the format I want with the above search but actually i dont because it returns nothing i think its because of the unauthorizedaccess crap when using get directories any solutions to bypass this.

Comment: Well if you don't have access then there's not much I can do there, you'll have to talk to your network administrator but you'll also need to justify why you need access as well